# It is possible to generate that Char in Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, whitespace

I have a fast question. It is possible to generate that Char in Google Charts? ... And mayby u knew how to do that (any advice or smth)? 
[Chart1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8tJ3.png)

This white area below the chart is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible

use `AreaChart` with `isStacked: true` and set the bottom area to `'transparent'`

since `isStacked: true`, most likely some data manipulation will be required to get the desired outcome

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(
      google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Bottom', 'Area 1', 'Area 2', 'Area 3'],
        ['2010', 100, 100, 100, 100],
        ['2020', 110, 120, 130, 140],
        ['2025', 120, 160, 180, 200],
        ['2030', 140, 180, 200, 240],
        ['2035', 200, 240, 280, 320],
        ['2040', 260, 300, 320, 380],
        ['2045', 320, 400, 460, 600],
        ['2050', 400, 480, 600, 800]
      ]),
      {
        areaOpacity: 1.0,
        colors: ['transparent', 'cyan', 'yellow', 'magenta'],
        lineWidth: 1,
        isStacked: true,
        series: {
          0: {
            visibleInLegend: false
          }
        }
      }
    );
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```