# Google Area Chart Fixed Values

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using Google Area Chart in ASP.NET MVC app.

The problem is that all areas take place from incoming value to 0.
I need to make, for example, area from 32 to 40, from 43 to 50.
At that time i didn't find the solution. Is it possible?

Comment: using a stacked area chart, you can set the first series as transparent, then use the second series to show the area from _32 to 40_, etc... -- [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38613827/5090771)

Comment: Thank you very much